# What does it mean for a function to be "invariant with respect to any linear transformation of the intependent variable"?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, numerical-methods

I am reading Numerical Analysis by Walter Gautschi, and one of the exercises says:

> Show that the elementary Lagrange interpolation polynomials $\ell_i(x)$ are invariant with respect to any linear transformation of the independent variable.

Could you please help me understand what this means? The only interpretation I can think of is $\forall x \forall c: \ell_i(x) = \ell_i(cx)$, but this is clearly not true.

Comment: It may mean that the set $\mathscr L$ of all such polynomials is invariant. In other words, if $f(x)$ is such a polynomial, then so is $f(L(x))$ for every linear transformation $L:X\to X$ of the domain $X$ of these polynomials (presumably $X=\mathbb R$?). It wouldn't be the *same* polynomial, just another member of that family. Only guessing here, of course. Said differently, $f\in\mathscr L\implies f\circ L\in\mathscr L$.

Comment: @MPW Oh thanks a lot I will try that!

Comment: Note also that if these are multivariable polynomials, say $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, then there are lots more linear transformations than just $x\mapsto cx$.

Comment: @MPW Oh right; fortunately these are univariate. I guess in the multivariate case, we would have to let $c$ be any $n \times n$ matrix.